# quickest way to check existance of multiple files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

What would be the best approach in python to check the existence of many millions of file paths, identifying paths that do not exist? I am currently using a single thread, something like:

```
 paths_not_existing = set()
 all_file_paths = [long_list]
 for path_name in all_file_paths:
     if os.path.isfile(path_name) == False:
         paths_not_existing.add(path_name)
```

Is it likely that multi-threading will give any speed up? Specifically, since I assume that this is I/O bound, I was wondering if there a way to look up multiple paths at the same time?

(in case of reference, the hard-drive that i am using is not solid state).

Comment: Using a comprehension will speed things up...

`nonexistent_paths = {path_name for path_name in all_file_paths if not os.path.isfile(path_name) }`. Or filtering down.

`nonexistent_paths = set(filter(lambda f: not os.path.isfile(f), all_file_paths))`

Comment: If these paths are in a tree it could also be a lot more efficient to not look for paths if it's already established that a parent doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use multithreading/processing, and it should give you a speedup.  There are lots of different ways to do it, but the easiest is probably with `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, which works the same as python's built in `map` function, but with distribution over cores.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
ncores = #number of cores, e.g. 8
pool = Pool(ncores) 

all_file_paths = np.array(long_array)

# create a list of booleans corresponding to whether
# each file is in your path or not.
selector = np.array(pool.map(os.path.isfile,all_file_paths))

paths_not_existing = all_file_paths[selector]
```